# Reselect createSelector by id

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reselect

I am using reselect lib in my React project.

I've created `Posts` selector which works fine. Here's the code

```
// selectors.ts

const getPosts = (state: RootState) => state.posts.posts;

export const getPostsSelector = createSelector(getPosts, (posts) => posts);
```

And I call it on my page like that

```
// SomePage.tsx    
const posts = useSelector(getPostsSelector);
```

Now I need to get a post by id. I thought to do it like that:

```
// selectors.ts

const getPostDetail = (state: RootState) =>
  state.posts.posts.entities[ID];

export const getPostsById = createSelector(
  getPostDetail,
  (detail) => detail
);
```

And call it on the page:

```
const PostDetail = useSelector(getPostsById);
```

I have two questions:

- Is it right approach to get single post?
- If it is, how to pass ID of the post if not, how to handle this the right way?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that `react-redux` as a HOC has the `connect(...)` function, which allows selectors to be `(state, props) => ...`, whereas `useSelector` only passes `(state) => ...`.

To allow still passing props, you could implement `useSelectorWithProps`:

```
function useSelectorWithProps (selector, props, deps, equalityFn) {
  const selectorFn = useCallback(state => selector(state, props), deps)
  return useReduxSelector(
    selectorFn,
    equalityFn
  )
}
```

This then allows you to do:

```
// selectors.js

const selectPosts = (state) => state.posts.posts;

const selectPostById = createSelector(
  selectPosts,
  (_, props) => props.id,
  (posts, id) => posts[id]
)

// Or make a utility function for selecting the prop
const selectProp = (key, orDefault) => (_, props) => (props[key] || orDefault)

const selectPostById = createSelector(
  selectPosts,
  selectProp('id'),
  (posts, id) => posts[id]
)

// but don't do this, as it will de-optimize the memoization of reselect.
// `{id: 1} !== {id: 1}` and thus causes it to recalculate the selector
// (Keyword: referential equality)
const selectPostById = createSelector(
  selectPosts,
  (_, props) => props,
  (posts, { id }) => posts[id]
)
```

```
// component.js
function Component(props) {
  const value = useSelectorWithProps(
    selectPostById,
    { id: props.id }, // pass an object
    [ props.id ] // pass dependencies of the props-object
  )
}
```

It's how i've implemented it in the projects i work in.

This allows your full "selector logic" to still live in your selectors, making it easier to test and having to write less glue-code in hooks.

It also allows you to use the same selectors for both `connect(...)` and `useSelectorWithProps(..)` might you want to.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* really the correct approach to select by specific `id`. The `useSelector` hook doesn't allow for passing more than just `state` to the selector.

A roundabout solution could be to store a `specific` post `id` also into state and select that as well. The downside is that the post will be unavailable on the initial render and you will need to dispatch (from `useEffect` hook or callback) an action to store the post `id` you want.

```
const getPostById = createSelector(
  [getPostsSelector, getPostId],
  (posts, id) => posts.find(post => post.id === id);
);
```

Usage:

```
const postById = useSelector(getPostById);

...

dispatch(setPostId(postId)); // store the id
```

Since you can't create a selector to return a specific post by `id` directly, then I suggest to instead create a selector that returns a derived state object of posts that lends itself to faster lookups, i.e. a map or object.

Example:

```
const postDetailMap = createSelector(
  [getPosts],
  posts => posts.reduce((posts, post) => ({
    ...posts,
    [post.id]: post,
  }), {}),
);
```

Usage:

```
const postsMap = useSelector(postDetailMap);

const specificPost = postMap[postId];
```

You may be able to abstract this into a custom hook though.

```
const useGetPostById = id => {
  const postsMap = useSelector(postDetailMap);
  return postsMap[id];
}
```

Usage:

```
const post = useGetPostById(postId);
```

Comment: What about performance issues because of `postDetailMap` call on each render?

Comment: @АртёмГанев Reselect creates memoized selectors, so this `postDetailMap` selector only recomputes when any of its input selectors update. The performance issue should be minimal, if any at all.